# Automapper Profiles not being loaded in Startup?

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using:

- AutoMapper 6.1.1
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
  3.0.1

It seems my profiles are not being loaded, every time I call the mapper.map I get **AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'**

Here my Startup.cs class ConfigureServices method

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        //register automapper

        services.AddAutoMapper();
        .
        .
    }
```

In another project called xxxMappings I have my mapping profiles.
Example class

```
public class StatusMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public StatusMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Status, StatusDTO>()
         .ForMember(t => t.Id, s => s.MapFrom(d => d.Id))
         .ForMember(t => t.Title, s => s.MapFrom(d => d.Name))
         .ForMember(t => t.Color, s => s.MapFrom(d => d.Color));

    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```

And call the map this way in a service class

```
    public StatusDTO GetById(int statusId)
    {
        var status = statusRepository.GetById(statusId);
        return mapper.Map<Status, StatusDTO>(status); //map exception here
    }
```

status has values after calling statusRepository.GetById

For my Profile classes, if instead of inherit from Profile I inherit from MapperConfigurationExpression I got a unit test like the one below saying the mapping is good.

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestStatusMapping()
    {
        var mappingProfile = new StatusMappingProfile();

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(mappingProfile);
        var mapper = new AutoMapper.Mapper(config);

        (mapper as IMapper).ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
```

My guess is that my mappings are not being initialized.
How can I check that? Am I missing something?
I saw an overload for AddAutoMapper() method

```
services.AddAutoMapper(params Assembly[] assemblies)
```

Should I pass all the assemblies in my xxxMappings project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figure it out. Since my mappings are in a different project, I did two things

1. From my API project (where Startup.cs is located, added a reference to my xxxMapprings project)
2. in ConfigureServices I used the overload  AddAutoMapper that gets an Assembly:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc();

       //register automapper
       services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StatusMappingProfile))); //If you have other mapping profiles defined, that profiles will be loaded too.
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution for fixing the issue when we have mapping profiles in different projects in a solution is:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Comment: Yezzz! I Wish I could vote you up twice.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create AutoMapperProfile inherit Profile Class**

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
   public AutoMapperProfile() 
    {
        ConfigureMappings();
    }
    private void ConfigureMappings()
    {
       //  DriverModel and Driver mapping classes
       CreateMap<DriverModel, Driver>().ReverseMap();
    } 
}
```

**2. Register this profile in Configuration service**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, it says "Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.Mapper' while attempting to activate". The profile is not being runned.