# AutoMapper throws Unmapped property exception despite ignore operation is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm trying to map my DTO class to the native one. Here are the classes:

```
public class CategoryResource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryToProduct> Products { get; set; }

        public Category()
        {
            Products = new Collection<CategoryToProduct>();
        }
    }
```

and the usage

```
var category = mapper.Map<CategoryResource, Category>(categoryResource);
```

As above code throws an error of this kind:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   =========================================================================== CategoryResource -> Category (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: Products

I changed my mapping profile to:

```
CreateMap<CategoryResource, Category>()
                .ForMember(x=>x.Products, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But still, I have the same error.
Could you please advice me what I do wrong here? 
I already restarted the IIS and AutoMapper version is 6.2.2

---

To answer question from comments, that's the whole MappingProfile

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            //Domain to API
            CreateMap<Type, TypeResource>();
            CreateMap<Unit, UnitResource>();
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryResource>();


            //API to domain
            CreateMap<TypeResource, Type>();
            CreateMap<UnitResource, Unit>();

            CreateMap<CategoryResource, Category>()
                .ForMember(x=>x.Products, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the properties one by one to try and narrow down which is causing the issue.

Comment: Would you share "CreateMap" initialization ?

Comment: You mean whole Mapping profile? I updated the question with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [6.2](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v6.2.0), AutoMapper *creates type maps on the fly* (documented [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html)):

> When you call Mapper.Map for the first time, AutoMapper will create the type map configuration and compile the mapping plan.

Given that the only thing `MappingProfile` is doing in your example code is ignoring the `Products` property, this leads me to believe that `MapperProfile` is not being registered.

See [Integrating AutoMapper with ASP.NET Core DI](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/) by Jimmy Bogard for more details on how to register your custom `Profile`s. To summarise, you can use the [AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) nuget package and either use the defaults or provide your own list of assemblies that need to be scanned.

Comment: Thank you @serpent5, sorry for delay. Yes, there was a problem with loading `MappingProfile` indeed. Your comprehensive answer brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312663/2395747), where I found that I have mine in separated assembly. Cheers!